# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error on localhost - AMPPS on OSX

Tags: php, osx-elcapitan, ampps

I have AMPPS installed on OSX. It was working fine with the previous osx version but with the new elcapitan i have ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error when i'm browsing my websites on localhost. It doesn't happen all the time but only when the website is using curl php function. It happens on all browsers, chrome, safari etc. 
Any idea how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with AMPPS and a Wordpress installation in OS X El Capitain. I could fix by changing the following configurations in the PHP.ini

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

Then after that you can

```
sudo chmod 7777 /tmp
```

This will ask for your administrator password.

Other users say that they could also fix this by just restarting Apache and MySQL, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Happening for me as well. Above solution didn't work.